# Issue using Buster: Captcha Solver for Humans extension with Selenium in development browser

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, recaptcha

I'm experiencing difficulties using the Buster: Captcha Solver for Humans extension alongside Selenium and Python. When accessing the site in the development browser, the extension is not displayed, although it works fine in my local browser. How can I resolve this issue and ensure that the extension is recognized during code execution in the development environment?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l9D5k.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zp1cU.png)

Despite my efforts, I haven't been able to resolve the problem with the Buster: Captcha Solver for Humans extension while using Selenium. Even after trying various approaches, the extension is not visible when accessing the site in the development browser. Any further guidance or solutions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I'm working on a Python automation project using Selenium, but the website I'm accessing has a Captcha. I installed a "Buster" extension in my browser to solve the Captcha (which uses the Google API). However, when I run the code, it opens the edgedriver, but the installed extension doesn't appear. What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

The Selenium starts a clean Private Browser for working. Your profiles, history, bookmarks, and extensions are not imported in that. It is like an Incognito Browser with clean profile.

While using Selenium, if you want to add an extension, you will have to do it manually.

For doing so, you have to download CRX or ZIP file of the extension, add it in your project. Then

```
driver = ""

def add_extension():
    global driver
    options = Options()
    options.add_extension('path_of_file/Captcha-Solver.crx')
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
```

This will add extension in your Selenium on start up.

CRX file can be download using a Chrome extension name "CRX EXTRACTOR".